# Reproject GeoJSON with OpenLayers 5

Tags: openlayers, geodjango

I'm using GeoDjango to render many points on a map based on OpenLayers 5.
My points have EPSG 4326 and the map has EPSG 3857, I need to reproject the points.
On the [OpenLayers API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GeoJSON.html) I've founded two parameters that are useful: dataProjection and featureProjection.

I've used they:

```
var geojsonObject = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "EPSG:4326"
    }
  },
  "features": [{% for d in geometry %}
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "pk": "{{ d.pk }}"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [{{ d.coord_lon_lat }}]
      }
    {% if forloop.last %}} {% else %}}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}
  ]
}

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: new ol.source.Vector({
   format: (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    })).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
 }),
 style: new ol.style.Style({
 ...
 }),
});

var OpenStreetMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
....
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    OpenStreetMap,
    vectorLayer,
  ],
  target: 'map',
    render: 'canvas',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0.0, 0.0],
    zoom: 2,
  })
});
```

But I don't see any points on the map. Why?

If I use the serialization of GeoJSON I can see all points on the map.

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '{% url 'points_geojson' %}',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  }),
 style :new ol.style.Style({
     image: new ol.style.Circle({
         radius: 7,
         stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
           color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)',
           width: 3,
         }),
         fill: new ol.style.Fill({
           color: 'rgba(200,200,200,1.0)'
         })
     }),
 }),
});
```

**GeoJSON**

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "EPSG:4326"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "pk": "40"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          14.243133533746002,
          40.840827040200026
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "pk": "41"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -73.16601634025572,
          40.84706035607121
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "pk": "42"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          138.602233864367,
          -34.89944783005726
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your GeoJSON object looks like some kind of a template. I suppose it has something to do with Geodjango. Are you sure it's correctly rendered to actual GeoJSON?

Comment: I'm sure because I've put the GeoJSON produced with the template on geojson.io and I can see all the points http://geojson.io/#id=gist:MaxDragonheart/0921214f4a61f3bc7ff22dc23f1a200e&map=2/4.0/32.7

Comment: Yes, but when is this rendering to final GeoJSON happening? Before `.readFeatures` gets it, or after? I suspect problem lies here.

Comment: With serialize I have the same GeoJSON. If I use the serialization of GeoJSON I can see all points on the map but If I copy and paste the GeoJSON into `geojsonObject`(without the template) I don't see any points. The rendering of the GeoJSON happen before `.readFeatures`

Comment: Can you publish a piece of this GeoJSON with a few points?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you published your GeoJSON, I finally noticed that error lies in the way you are trying to read GeoJSON. You cannot read it when specifying format, you have to use `features` option for this. Then you don't have to specify format at all:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: new ol.source.Vector({
   features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
     dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
     featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
   })).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
 }),
 style: new ol.style.Style({
 ...
 }),
});
```

Comment: Very, very thank you!